# Linq multiple join query

Tags: wpf, linq

I have Two tables whose schema is as under:

Table 1:-

```
ID int
first_name string
last_name string
```

Table2:-

```
ID int
Address1
Address2
```

I have a Viewmodel as follows where i am using a Linq.Join() to concatenate data from these two tables into a third table as follows:-

```
public class VM_JoinData:INotifyPropertyChanged
 {
     public int ID {get;set;}
     public string first_name {get;set;}
     public string last_name {get;set;}
     public string Address1 {get;set;}
     public string Address1 {get;set;}
     private List<DM_JoinData> AllViewData = null;
     public VM_JoinData()
     {
        AllViewData=(from Tab1 in Table_1
                       join Tab2 in Table2 on Tab1.ID equals Tab2.ID
                       select new
                       DM_JoinData
                       {
                         ID=Tab1.ID,
                         first_name=Tab1.first_name,
                         last_name=Tab1.last_name,
                         Address1=Tab2.Address1,
                         Address2=Tab2.Address2
                       }
                 ).ToList<DM_JoinData>();
      }
 }
```

There are many DataModels that i need to join and fetch common fields into a List<> in my ViewModel,but each time i require creation of a new ViewModel,i first have to create a DataModel representing all the fields of the new ViewModel ,and then i have to instantiate a new DataModel and then assign each and every field of this DataModel instance individually with its corresponding value from the join elements in my Linq.Join() query as shown here.This becomes cumbersome as the number of DataModels and number of fields increase.

NOTE:

1)Assume that i have implemented INotifyPropertyChanged in the setter of all the properties of VM_JoinData,which is my ViewModel.

2)Table_1 and Table_2 in Linq.Join are either Lists<> or some DBContext from EntityFramework.

How can i create a new ViewModel without creating a replica DataModel first ,and without having to specify each and every property of DataModel in the List in ViewModel individually in the Linq.Join() query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course you need to actually fetch the data from the database before you can use any data values. You don't need to create a `List<DM_JoinData>` though.

The query must however return some kind of data object that holds the actual values. Where else are you supposed to get these from?

You could just issue the query using an anonymous type and set the properties of the view model:

```
public class VM_JoinData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public string first_name { get; set; }
    public string last_name { get; set; }
    public string Address1 { get; set; }
    public string Address2 { get; set; }

    public VM_JoinData()
    {
        var query = (from Tab1 in Table_1
                     join Tab2 in Table2 on Tab1.ID equals Tab2.ID
                     select new
                     {
                         ID = Tab1.ID,
                         first_name = Tab1.first_name,
                         last_name = Tab1.last_name,
                         Address1 = Tab2.Address1,
                         Address2 = Tab2.Address2
                     }).FirstOrDefault();

        if (query != null)
        {
            ID = query.ID;
            first_name = query.first_name;
            last_name = query.last_name;
            Address1 = query.Address1;
            Address2 = query.Address1;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

The other option would be to issue the query before you create the view model:

```
VM_JoinData vm = (from Tab1 in Table_1
                  join Tab2 in Table2 on Tab1.ID equals Tab2.ID
                  select new VM_JoinData
                        {
                            ID = Tab1.ID,
                            first_name = Tab1.first_name,
                            last_name = Tab1.last_name,
                            Address1 = Tab2.Address1,
                            Address2 = Tab2.Address2
                        }).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: tx mm8,I have tried the second approach already and got my hands burnt :-). because each time a new instance of ViewModel is created,it fires up the constructor which in turn populates a whole lot of other lists which i w don't want with each instance of VM_Model.However,i will try the first option which will spare me the horror of creating a new DataModel everytime i create a new ViewModel. thanks mm8